# How can I know FTP-username and Password

Tags: linux, passwords, ftp, console

I hired a freelancer to install my website to a new server. However, I don't know/remember FTP username/password any more. But I have username/password for linux-console. Is there some EASY and SAFE way to get these FTP-details?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the credentials for the linux console?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you don't have superuser (root) access to the server? Is it hosted with a third party?

Comment: Your question begs the question: why are you not able to ask the freelancer? If they are professional then they should have zero issues giving you the credentials again.

Comment: Just create a new FTP username and password and delete the old one.

Answer (score -2):

The ID/password that you know were established when the Operating System was installed.
Somebody logged-in to the "Management" site, with some other credentials, and booted from a (real? virtual?) Linux CD/DVD, and installed the Operating System.

So, if you don't have those credentials, you need to contact the hosting-company that hosts your (real? virtual?) system, identify yourself, and they will re-issue the credentials.